# Ghostscript output to file: what could cause this error?

Tags: image, ghostscript

I am attempting to produce a file for printing a map from a Ghostscript program. It reads data from an input file with 1320 longitude and latitude coordinates, one per line, like this

-92.32  48.24
-88.13  48.92
-83.11  46.27
-81.66  44.76
-82.09  42.29

The file is opened and read with this code:

/ifile (/home/Harry/Mercator/world.dat) (r) file def
ifile s readline

Running the program with `gs Arc17.ps` gives me the output I want, with no problem

However when I try to get an image file with:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sDEVICE=png16mdGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=Arc17.png Arc17.ps
```

(command copied from `https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm#Measurements`, section 3.1 "PNG file format" I get this error

```
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--
Operand stack:
   ifile   (/home/Harry/Mercator/world.dat)   (r)
```

Please can anyone explain this and tell me what to do? I will happily supply any more details, not sure what more to include at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using -dSAFER which specifically restricts arbitrary file access for security reasons. When -dSAFER is true you may not open/read/write from arbitrary locations in the file system.

If you want to do this, set -dNOSAFER (or just don't set SAFER).

The invalidfileaccess error means pretty much exactly what it says, there was an attempt to access a file, and that access was illegal.

The various switches in that command line are explained in the same documentation you referenced, mostly in the 'Use.htm' file.

Comment: Thank you KenS. So obvious now you have pointed it out, but with no idea where to start I was overwhelmed by the detail. Perfect result now. Brilliant, wish I could up the points more.